# Cost efficiencies and scalability in firestore with reports

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In firestore sub-collections should be generated to save costs. In this case I intend to have a document for each user who registers and to go nesting the other data that I need from these. In this way, I will have only one reading per user who enters and the other information will be included in the sub-collections, according to the [firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model).

The future problem is the reports. If there are 100 users, if it is required to have a complete report with these, it would be 100 readings, when there are 50,000 users it will be the same. Additionally, although I do not know the topic of snapshots well, each of these will generate an additional cost for updates.

I would like if someone can support me with suggestions or help me clarify this:

- Is it possible to have a main document that contains all the information and is this the one that is used for reports and for users get the data? That is, instead of having N documents for each user, have a single document "maindoc" and this would have subcollections with all the user data

**Note:** to complement solutions for reports such as data export to Bigquery and the API service, I do not consider them relevant since they also occupy N reads according to the number of documents

Answer (score 1):

> I will have only one reading per user who enters and the other information will be included in the sub-collections

Not really, since Firestore queries are *shallow* by nature, which means it does not return the value of the sub-collections when you get the document. Sub-collections are there to make data easier to understand, not to save cost. Maybe check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48084825/firestore-deep-queries) question out for more infomation.

> The future problem is the reports

You get billed 0.06$ for every 100,000 document reads (that the price for my region, yours may differs), so unless you need to use the reports function mutiple times a day *and* having millions of documents, I think it's ok.

> Is it possible to have a main document that contains all the information and is this the one that is used for reports and for users get the data?

This is a really bad idea, because you not only get billed for document reads, you also get billed for network egress, a.k.a the amount of network bandwidth that you use. Doing things this way mean every user have to download a giant document which slows down the app *and* take a lot of bandwidth.

> Would it be a better option to look at SQL alternatives that have their cost base based on data size and not reads/writes?

This comes down to your use case. But for me, the different in pricing is not that much considering other BaaS options where Firebase documentations is very hard to beat.

Comment: thanks for the clarifications, it is quite valid. It is not easy to find a solution as complete as firebase

Comment: glad i could help